# Not Getting Dialogflow Fulfillment Inline Editor response in android

Tags: android, dialogflow-es

I am integrating an android chat app with Dialogflow. The integration part has been successful, and I am able to display the default text response for a particular query in android.

But when I tried the Inline Editor Fulfilment, The response from Inline Editor Fulfillment is not getting displayed in android. I wanted to display response from Inline editor in android.

I have enabled the fulfillment in the Intents and tried by removing the default text responses, but still it is not working.

I used the method
    `result.getFulfillment().getSpeech()`
for displaying the response from dialogflow, which is working for default responses from intents. Is there any other method for displaying response from Inline Editor Fulfilment.

I just want to display the simple response from **Inline Editor Fulfillment** to **Android**.

Adding the inline editor code below

```
  // See https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs
  // for Dialogflow fulfillment library docs, samples, and to report issues
  'use strict';

  const functions = require('firebase-functions');
  const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
  const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

  process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

  exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment =
    functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
      const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
      console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' +
        JSON.stringify(request.headers));
      console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' +
        JSON.stringify(request.body));

      function welcome(agent) {
        agent.add(`Welcome to Chess Master How can I assist you! `);
      }

      function fallback(agent) {
        agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
        agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
      }
      function RuyLopez(agent) {
        agent.add(`For Ruy Lopez, Please visit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruy_Lopez`);
        agent.add(new Card({
            title: `Ruy Lopez`,

            imageUrl:
              'https://store.chessclub.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab    3 3525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/r/u/ruy-lopez-store-large-no-sale_1.jpg',
            text: `Please vist \n https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruy_Lopez`,
            buttonText: 'Visit Website',
            buttonUrl: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruy_Lopez'
          })
        );
        //agent.add(new Suggestion(`Quick Reply`));
        //agent.add(new Suggestion(`Suggestion`));
        //agent.setContext({ name: 'weather', lifespan: 2, parameters: { city:'Rome' }});
      }

      let intentMap = new Map();
      intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
      intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
      intentMap.set('Ruy Lopez', RuyLopez);
      // intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
      agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code from the inline editor that you're using?

Comment: did you enable webhook for your intent?

Comment: @AbhinavTyagi , I have enabled webhook for intent

Comment: @Prisoner , I've updated the inline editor code in question